# How to List / Export ALL "Company owned" devices?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

The command is suppose to Retrieves a paginated list of all mobile devices for an account.

[Mobiledevices: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list)

Currently, it's returning ONLY devices with ownership "**User owned**".

We are missing ALL the devices set as "**Company owned**".

Thanks

Comment: Are you the account administrator? Did you try the option "customerId" - "my_customer"? How do you set your devices as "Company owned"?

Answer (score 0):

### You seem not to be alone with this issue

Indeed the issue is already reported on [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/62124267). I recommend you to "star" this issue and follow the updates on its solution.